# Python - creating a simple killswitch for a function that runs with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, keystroke

So, i would claim that i understand how Asyncio, Multiprocessing, Threading etc. works, basically. I know how to listen for keystrokes too - there are many good examples on this site.

However i was unable to combine both into one. I have a programm that runs continously in a loop, until it runs into certain cases where it stops. In these cases, it uses a `Multiprocessing.Queue()` to prompt for user input on wether it should continue or not.

All of this works, so far so good. Now i want to add a second catch case here: The programm should, once it starts running, immediatly cease working as soon as i press a certain button (lets say Escape).

This is the very dumbed down version of my programm:

test.py:

```
from test3 import Counter
from multiprocessing import Process,  Queue
import sys

def main(q, passed_variable):
    foo = Counter()
    p1 = Process(target=foo.counting, args=(q,passed_variable))
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    if q.get() == False:
        x = input("Keep going?")
        print(x)
        if x == "y":
            main(q, user_Input)
        else:
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()

    user_Input = ("What you want from me, man?")
    print("Starting")
    main(q, passed_variable=user_Input)
```

test3.py:

```
import time

class Counter:
    def counting(self, q, user_input):
        x = 0
        while True:
            print(str(x) + " " + user_input)

            if x == 4:
                q.put(False)
                break

            time.sleep(1)
            x += 1
```

I tried everything i could think of, in no case did i get the desired result, and no question i found here was able to help me in this specific case.

Comment: You'd want to pass a `multiprocessing.Event` as an argument, then call `.set()` on it in the parent and check for `.is_set()` it in the child process's function.

Answer (score 0):

The crux is:

```
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
```

Which means after `main()` starts p1, it waits for it to finish.  So there's no chance to interrupt it while processing.

You need to:

1. wait for p1 to finish
2. while waiting, see if the main process gets a 'q'
3. if the main process gets a 'q', stop it.

Something like:

```
    p1.start()
    while p1.is_alive():
        k = keyboard.read_key()
        if k == 'q':
            p1.terminate()
```

Comment: i have a similar problem, i understand what you mean but how can i solve this then? is the .join() the issue here? how would you have to change OPs code to make it not wait for p1 to finish?

Comment: thanks for your reply - if this isnt possible, then what can i do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using `keyboard` and then creating a second `Queue()`:

```
from test3 import Counter
from multiprocessing import Process,  Queue
import sys
import keyboard

def main(q, queue2, passed_variable):
    foo = Counter()
    p1 = Process(target=foo.counting, args=(q,passed_variable))
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=keyCatcher, args=(queue2,))
    p2.start()

    if queue2.get() == False:
        p1.terminate()

        print("Terminating Programm")
        sys.exit()

    if q.get() == False:
        x = input("Keep going?")
        print(x)
        if x == "y":
            main(q, queue2, user_Input)
        else:
            sys.exit()

def keyCatcher(queue2):
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed
            queue2.put(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    queue2 = Queue()

    user_Input = ("What you want from me, man?")
    print("Starting")
    main(q, queue2, passed_variable=user_Input)
```